# Local application launchers don't work if you access GNOME Shell via XRDP, is it a configuration or permissions issue?

Tags: gnome-shell, xrdp

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V using the image from the Hyper-V Quick Create Gallery and configured RDP access. Then I installed the latest version of Eclipse using Ubuntu Make: `umake ide eclipse`

Ubuntu Make placed a launcher in `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse-java.desktop` and everything works fine, I can find the application and add it to my favorites.

But if I access Ubuntu via rdp (Hyper-V "advanced session") things don't work anymore, I can't find the application and the favorite I previously added is not shown in the sidebar, as if GNOME Shell didn't take into account the contents of the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

What additional configuration do I need to make local launchers work?

Here is some additional info about my system:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.4
```